# What can I do to put in a new light here

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, light

I’m looking to add a new light here, when I wire it all up I can not push the wires up into the box, what should I do, you can still see the wires from the new light? [image]

Comment: That old insulation is *scary*. I'd recommend taping it - any color but white or green on hot/switched hot, white on neutral.

Comment: Looks like the old light had a large canopy that hid the wires without pushing them into the box.   That's the smallest junction box I've ever seen. It looks like the diameter isn't even the length of two wire nuts.   Does the new light have a canopy as small as the box?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the light bracket and wrap the wires around the inside of the box. Leave the wire nuts out just enough to make the connections and reinstall the light bracket. Make your fixture connections, shove the wire nuts up into the box and mount your light